# The best way to judge the capacitive and inductive load

Tags: adc

I've a ADC sampling system. What I can get from the connected load is the sampled data of the output voltage and output current. I want to know if the load is capacitve or inductive from these datas. For a pure AC wave, I can get the information from the time of the 'zero crossover' point. But in my situation the AC may contain high frequency harmonics. Does the 'zero crossover' method still work? Is there other (faster) method to do this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most popular method to obtain harmonics from a signal is digital filtering. Most method use Fast Fourier Transformation (FFT). You can google it, because the theory is quite broad.

The discipline which covers transforming analogue to digital signals and use them later is called Digital Signal Processing (DSP). The literature in this topic is also broad, there are some free books available online (you may start with [this one](http://www.dspguide.com/)).

The main idea of this approach is to use [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) to obtain all harmonics, including DC component (the 0th harmonic). The highest harmonic one can measure is determined by sampling rate (see [Shannon theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem)).

You should convert samples of voltage and current to their complex form (see [phasor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor)) and divide one by another, so you can get the complex impedance, which is easy to calculate the angle. If the phase shift is the only thing you are interested in, you can just subtract the phase angles of voltage and current.

For any n-harmonic (for $$n \geq 1$$) the characteristic of load does not change. So for any capacitor, for any harmonic, current is always leading, and for any inductor the current is always lagging. There will be differences between the phase shifts for each harmonic. The reactance of an inductor, for n-th harmonic is $$X = n \omega L $$, while for a capacitor it is always $$X = \frac {1}{n \omega C}$$.

Because it is numerically easier to handle higher values than lower ones, you may check for each harmonic (for example first 10), for which one the voltage and current are the largest and then divide them. However, you should get correct results even for the 1st harmonic.

**UPDATE**

In your case the zero-cross method is not valid. In general, there is a possibility that each harmonic has different phase angle. If they are combined, there can be many zero crossings in a single period. You will not know which one crosses the zero in which moment, if you do not decompose them. You can also miss the zero crossing, for example there is large DC component (say 10 Volts), and low 1st harmonic (say 1 Volt). You will never get a zero-crossing in this case, but it is possible to measure the impedance for the 1st harmonic (and thus its angle).

Answer (score 0):

If you have both current and voltage waveforms, you could filter the output digitally (or analog, but it's difficult to get two filters which are exactly the same), and remove any high frequency components.

There are plenty of digital lowpass filter design sites on the 'net, which even should you the code you have to use in the program. You can even use one of the many audio processing programs which can apply filters.

After the filtering you use the phase difference to see if the load is capacitive (current is leading the voltage) or inductive (current is lagging), and by how much.

Answer (score 0):

Use the load voltage signal to produce a -90 degree (lagging) shifted reference waveform (maybe with a couple of low pass filters). The lag produces a reference waveform that "looks" like the load current of a pure inductor.

Take this reference and convert to a logic square wave using a comparator/schmitt trigger. Use this to control an analogue switch. The signal input to the analogue switch is a voltage representation of the actual load current.

The analogue switch is now performing synchronous rectification of the load current representative waveform. If the output waveform averages at a negative value then the current through the load is capacitive. If the average output is a positive voltage then the load is more dominated by inductance.

Here's a picture of an input sinewave and how it can be "synchronously rectified" by a square wave: -

[image]

The example above is for a -90 degree shifted reference sq wave - the output has an average value of zero and the load is therefore resistive.

Comment: Thanks, I think in your method, the key point is my filter must can filter the harmonics to enough low, right?

Comment: Just a good low pass filter of maybe 1Hz 3dB point and a multimeter will give you results. Do you have a simulation tool?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your method should work, I'll try it later, but now I can only change the software, so a method in **coding** stage may be better:)